# How to suppress empty space if memo is empty

Tags: fastreport

I have a report that display some text fields one of them is a blob field I display it in TfrxMemoView but sometimes that blob field is empty so I dont want the TfrxMemoView to take any empty space in the printed page, in other words how to suppress the empty space when blob field is empty ?

I am using Fast Report VCL.

Comment: Can't you just put a conditional in the erb or whatever you are using to generate your html?  like <%=  @blob_field if @blobfield%>.  I dunno I am not a front end guy but this would work

Comment: no I can not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place TfrxMemoView on the separate Child stretched band and show/hide this band in the script depend of your blob field content